# Parameter Server Strategy with estimators(Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

How can I do distributed training using Parameter Server Strategy with estimators? How to define Cluster Spec without using TF_CONFIG for Estimators?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, using the Environment variable, TF_CONFIG is mandatory in order to use Parameter Server Distributed Strategy, in which we define the Cluster Spec, the PS information and the information about Tasks, in json format.

Please find the code snippet below which demonstrates distributed training using Parameter Server Strategy with estimators:

```py
    # Configuring the Workers, Parameter Servers and Tasks
    NUM_WORKERS = 1
    IP_ADDRS = ['localhost']
    PORTS = [12345]

    os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({
            'cluster': {
                'worker': ['%s:%d' % (IP_ADDRS[w], PORTS[w]) for w in range(NUM_WORKERS)],
                'ps': ['%s:%d' % (IP_ADDRS[w], PORTS[w]) for w in range(NUM_WORKERS)]
            },
            'task': {'type': 'worker', 'index': 0}
        })

    # Method for using ParamterServerStrategy
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.ParameterServerStrategy()

    config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(train_distribute=strategy)

    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn, model_dir='/tmp/multiworker', config=config)
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
        classifier,
        train_spec=tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=input_fn),
        eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=input_fn)
    )
```